# how to create a duplicate a copy from a template google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two google spreadsheets. One is a template, and the other is a Master spreadsheet containing people's names, emails, and a link to a copy of the template spreadsheet.

I wanted to automate part of the process, but I'm new to GAS and JavaScript.

I need help copying the template and access the link to this new file, so I can add this link to the master spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided a sample code below showing what it will look like. You can start from here:

```
function copyTemplateAddLink() {
  // Sheet IDs are found in the url after "/d/", see images below
  var masterID = '1CGsdAm2ewyUYyOPcTF97uxkbdAhNlxstCH09f9BHnZs';
  var templateID = '1hJ0Ze04NeCUzG8tkWPfUZOuHhEQb-dvocquRUuwnqrM';

  // Setting link column to 3 as sample
  var linkColumn = '3';
  
  var masterSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterID);
  var templateSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(templateID);

  // Copy template
  var templateCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(templateSheet.getId()).makeCopy("Copy of Template Sheet");

  // Get url/link of the said copied template and then add it next to the bottom row, on column set above
  masterSheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(masterSheet.getLastRow() + 1, linkColumn, 1, 1).setValue(templateCopy.getUrl()); 
}
```

**Master before running the code:**

[image: master]

**Template:**

[image: template]

**Copy of Template generated:**

[image: copy]

**Master after running the code:**

[image: master after]

**References:**

- [Drive file documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#detailed-documentation)
- [Spreadsheet documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.